# npm ERR! weird error 8 in windows7

Tags: node.js, npm

Is there anybody meet the same wired issue when you are trying to run `npm install` under the company's proxy server? any help will be great thanks!

```
? tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
........
? tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)

stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
Error: connect ETIMEDOUT
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: ENOTEMPTY, rmdir 'C:\Anna\ACG\video-client\no
de_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\jpegtran-bin\node_modules\request
\node_modules'
npm ERR! error rolling back  grunt-contrib-imagemin@0.2.1 { [Error: ENOTEMPTY, r
mdir 'C:\Anna\ACG\video-client\node_modules\grunt-contrib-imagemin\node_modules\
jpegtran-bin\node_modules\request\node_modules']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 53,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'ENOTEMPTY',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: 'C:\\Anna\\ACG\\video-client\\node_modules\\
grunt-contrib-imagemin\\node_modules\\jpegtran-bin\\node_modules\\request\\node_
modules' }
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: I have the exact same error message. It is when npm is trying to install grunt-contrib-imagemin.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?